# How to calculate the number of recursive calls in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I was using the below given method to calculate height of a binary tree,

```
int height(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
       return 0;
    else
    {
        int lheight = height(root.left);
        int rheight = height(root.right);

        if (lheight > rheight)
            return(lheight+1);
        else return(rheight+1); 
    }
}
```

This returns lheight = 2. Initially I thought that lheight increments by 1 on each recursive call to height(root.left). But then I added a printf statement and ran it again,

```
int height(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
       return 0;
    else
    {
        int lheight = height(root.left);
        System.out.print(lheight);
        int rheight = height(root.right);

        if (lheight > rheight)
            return(lheight+1);
        else return(rheight+1); 
    }
}
```

The printf statement printed this 0 1 0 2 0. How is the value of lheight changing on each recursive call? I am not looking for a new solution. I know this can be done in many ways. I just want to understand what is going on in this code snippet. Here is the binary tree image link.
[Binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlIgg.gif)

Comment: You could add a global variable and increment it at the top of the function. Poor long term solution, but it would work. Also, please only add the relevant tags.

Comment: What is this, Java or C++? If Java, then the `printf` line probably won't compile.

Comment: Thanks but I wish to know how I am getting 0 1 0 2 0 and not simply 0 1 2.

Comment: There is a +1 missing somewhere. As is, your height should always be 0.

Comment: @RustyX sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Put up a **real** [mcve]. The code you are showing doesn't **increment** anything. It would produce 0 all the time. So whatever gives you 01 0 2 0 is **not** the code you are showing us here. There is no sense in asking about code that isnt in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pass in count as a parameter to your method, initially set at 0 or 1 (depending on your preference), and then increase it each time you recursively call the method.

EDIT: Being honest, I've not tested this code, so I can't figure out how you are supposed to be changing the height values. Feels like this will be infinitely recursive.

Anyway, here is the basic idea of tracking recursion count:

```
int height(Node root, int lCount, int rCount)
{
    if (root == null){
       return 0;
    }
    else {
        int lheight = height(root.left, lCount + 1, rCount);
        int rheight = height(root.right, lCount, rCount + 1);

        if (lheight > rheight){
            return(lheight);
        }
        else return(rheight); 
    }
}
```

You initialise the method call with **height(root, 0, 0)** and the very last execution of the L and R "branches" of execution *should* yield the respective totals.

Comment: I'm referring to the original code being out of control. The method of counting recursion I have suggested is not the "out of control" part.

Comment: I'll see what I can do, guvnor ;-)

Comment: I have removed the offending sentence :-p

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this -

```
int height(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
       return 0;
    else
    {
        return 1+ Math.max(height(root.left),height(root.right));
    }
}
```

To calculate height call like this

```
int height = height(root); //this is the height not inside the function
```

I have not compiled it - but this is the way to get the height of a tree (c/c++/java/..)

Answer (score 0):

The height of a tree is max of the height of it left sub tree and height of right sub tree. So If you see your code then it is recursively calculating the height of left and right sub tree and  checking which is max. If you realy want to visualize  it. make tree structure of the called method. You can easy visualise it.

Comment: Yes Swapan I get that but how is the value of lheight changing from 0 to1 to 0 to 2 to 0 and if it is 0 on the final call, how is it returning 2.

Comment: I think you need to change code 1+ max(lHeight,rHeight) instead of 
if (lheight > rheight)
            return(lheight);
        else return(rheight);

Answer (score 0):

Take this for example

```
        1

      /   \
    2      3
  /  \
4     5
```

First, 1 will pass its left [height(root.left)] so 2 will be called.Then 2 will pass its left so 4 will be called.Now 4 will call its left.

since 4 don't have any left it will pass null or 0 to **lheight**.So this time the code goes to next step ie to function [ height(root.right) ].

For the right of 4,  we have null so 0 will be returned to rheight. Now with help of
[ return(rheight+1); ] function, value 1 will be passed to calling the function 2.

so 2 will have lheight as 1.Now 2 will now call its right.And so on the loop continues and 2 will have two values l=1 and r= 1 and will return 1+1=2 to its calling function i.e 1 .

the right of 1 is called and it will return 1 with the same loop like before. And finally, we have l=2 and r=1. Therefore, our final value will be  [lheight+1]=3. so the height of a tree is 3

Answer (score -1):

you can create a global variable that is increased every time that the function call himself

```
int i;   //it has to be initialized with 0 


int height(Node root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else
    {
         i++;
         int lheight = height(root.left);
         printf("%d ", lheight);
         i++;
         int rheight = height(root.right);

         if (lheight > rheight)
             return(lheight);
         else return(rheight); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is better, but still a bad idea: using a **field** to be increased within a recursive method; that *screams* for creating obscure bugs. Super bad practice. The whole point of recursion is to be "self-contained"